# ¿Cómo calcular el Equal Error Rate(EER) para un modelo de más de dos clases?

Tags: tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Necesito medir el Equal Error Rate (**EER** en lo adelante) de un modelo LSTM que se encarga de predecir a que clase pertenece una muestra determinada de entre 5 posibles clases.

El problema es que he visto que el **EER** se calcula en base a la curva **ROC**(Receiver Operator Characteristics) o en base a las curvas de **FAR**(False Acept Rate) and **FRR**(False Reject Rate) y estas curvas se calculan en modelos binarios.

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de calcular el **EER** para mi modelo o como debo modelar el resultado del modelo para poder calcularle el **EER**.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Esta pregunta te podría servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339746/equal-error-rate-in-python

Comment: En esa pregunta se debate como calcular el EER para un modelo binario. Lo que quiero saber es si existe una forma para calcular el EER pero para un modelo de mas de dos clases.De todos modos gracias vichoko

Comment: arcanis-the-omnipotent le los artículos que me recomendaste. El problema es que mi duda no proviene de un código como tal, es más bien teórica por eso no agrego ejemplo mínimo verificable. Saludos